# How to take logs of a particular process in adb

Tags: android, adb

I want to take logs of particular application e.g music player in android. Logs through adb are full system logs but I want logs related a particular application. Each application has a DVM and each application dumps log at particular port number on DDMS. Is there any way to take out logs of particular application through port filtering. I am not talking about filtering through log tags. Please provide your guidance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

adb logcat packagename

Where packagename is the name of the package of the application you want to look at. The logcat commands can be found atL http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html

Comment: have you used it ?  I think you can filter it using tags but I want dump logs of a particular app. Correct me if write something wrong.